# create a .doc / pdf / odt using codeigniter and php

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, templates, doc

I followed this tut : 
http://klewos.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/using-php-to-fill-a-word-document-quick-tip/
and all is fine till i open the downloaded .doc into libre office,

instead of outputing the doc content, it shows the full xml code as content !

Just note that i would prefer to create a PDF as final document but it seems easier with doc

I should miss a step with the xml to doc ?

if someone sees a better way to do this kind of thing (my base doc is 10 pages long so i don't really want to create a line by line pdf)

Anyhelp is welcome ;)

Comment: The article you linked to generates Office 2003-specific XML files (unrelated to the Office 2007+ OfficeOpenXml standard). Libreoffice does not support these files, only the binary 97-2003 *.doc files and the OfficeOpenXml *.docx files.

Comment: you're right thanx for the info. I finally switched to using html2pdf instead of trying to get a doc/odt. 
Html2pdf seems great and flexible so now i generate a PDF from a html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article does mention that particular situation:

> I’ve tried to open the Word 2003 XML document in OpenOffice.org 3.1.
>   Unfortunately, Writer wasn’t fooled by the .doc extension and opened
>   the document as plain text. Only after changing the document’s
>   extension to .xml, the editor opened it correctly. So, the documents
>   are portable after all.